# how to bind inner repeater?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

i have a repeater inside another repeater. now i want to bind the inner repeater. but i m getting error of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". my code is

```
Protected Sub rep_test_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As   System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rep_test.ItemDataBound
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt = obj.getdata()
    Dim innerRepeater As Repeater = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("innerRepeater"), Repeater)
    innerRepeater.DataSource = dt
    innerRepeater.DataBind()
End Sub
```

my source code is

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rep_test" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div id='h<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex") %>' class="header" onclick='ToggleDisplay(<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex") %>);'>
                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID")%>
            </div>
            <div id='d<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex") %>' class="details">
            <asp:Repeater ID="rep_hello" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "batchid")%><br />
                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ts")%><br />
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            <%--    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "batchid")%><br />
                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ts")%><br />--%>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Could you show some of that repeater as well?

Comment: Where do you get the exception?  Is it actually finding the `innerRepeater`?  If it doesn't find it first then you can't bind to it.

Comment: now that error has been removed but still i m not able to see the data in inner repeater

Comment: one thing more i have remove the javascript to see the data in both of repeaters.Please help me as soon as possible. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a header or footer in the parent repeater, your method might be executed for them too, and hence not finding the inner control.

Try to check if the `e.Item.ItemType` is "only" either `ListItemType.Item` or `ListItemType.AlternatingItem`, and only execute your code in this case.

Of course can't guarantee if this is the problem. Check also for confirming that repeater ID is correct, and verify that it's directly inside the item template of the parent repeater, not inside another server control inside the item (or else, you'll need to find the other control first and then find the repeater inside it).

Also, ensure you are using `rep_hello` ID not `innerRepeater`.

BTW< you can do this in the markup too...

```
<asp:repeater runat="server" id="innerRepeater"
    DataSource='<%# Eval("PropertyInParentObject") %>'  >
    ....
    ....
</asp:repeater>
```

You can use `Container.DataItem` instead of `Eval` too (and cast it to the type of the object in parent repeater item).

Comment: sir i have checked the ids and there is no effect after changing Container.DataItem to Eval only. Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find a repeater with the ID "innerRepeater".
You should use "rep_hello" instead:

```
Protected Sub rep_test_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As   System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rep_test.ItemDataBound
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt = obj.getdata()
    Dim innerRepeater As Repeater = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("rep_hello"), Repeater)
    innerRepeater.DataSource = dt
    innerRepeater.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

the follwing links will help you the most
[efficient way binding nested repeater 3 levels deep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454129/efficient-way-binding-nested-repeater-3-levels-deep)

[msdn library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478959.aspx)