# efficient way binding nested repeater 3 levels deep

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have 3 levels deep repeters which bind to the following:

MainCategories - bind to top repeater

SubCategories - bind to repeater in the 2nd level

SubSubCategories - bind to repeater in the 3rd level

Up to now, I acheived the databinding by using the itemdatabound event of the repeaters and passing the category id in order to filter the level beneath (e.g.: get all SubCategories for MainCategory 1, get all Subcategoris for MainCategory2).
This of course results in many trips to the database, and is inefficient.

Is there a way to make only 3 queries:
1. get all Main Categories and bind to top rpeater,
2. get all sub categories and bind somehow  to 2nd level repeaters
3. get all subsub categories and bind to 3rd level repeaters.

How can this be acheived in asp.net c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do so, please follow below steps:

First of all data into a DataTable say `dataTableMainCategories` and then filter `SubCategories` and `SubSubCategories` from `dataTableMainCategories` data table. Finally, at `ItemDataBound` write below code block and for `SubCategories` and `SubSubCategories` DataTable add desired column before importing filtered rows.

Populate all main categories into a table and Bind to MainCategory repeater (`rptrMainCategories`) and the populate all sub and sub sub categories into `dataTableCategories` data table.

```
protected void rptrMainCategories_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Item.ItemType== ListItemType.Item)
    {
        int subCategoryID = 5; // Pass your subcategory id to be filtered
        Repeater rptrSubCategories = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptrSubCategories");
        DataTable dtSubCategory = new DataTable();
        dtSubCategory.Columns.Add(); // Add your columns as SubCatagory
        DataRow[] dataRows = dataTableCategories.Select("SubCategoryID= " + subCategoryID + "");
        foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataRows)
        {
            dtSubCategory.ImportRow(dataRow);
        }
        rptrSubCategories.DataSource = dtSubCategory;
        rptrSubCategories.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void rptrSubCategories_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Item.ItemType== ListItemType.Item)
    {
        int subSubCategoryID = 55; // Pass your subsubcategory id to be filtered
        Repeater rptrSubSubCategory = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptrSubSubCategory");
        DataTable dtSubSubCategory = new DataTable();
        dtSubSubCategory.Columns.Add(); // Add your columns as SubCatagory
        DataRow[] dataRows = dataTableCategories.Select("SubSubCategoryID= " + subSubCategoryID + "");
        foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataRows)
        {
            dtSubSubCategory.ImportRow(dataRow);
        }
        rptrSubSubCategory.DataSource = dtSubSubCategory;
        rptrSubSubCategory.DataBind();
    }
}
```

**Update**

If you use typed(custom typed) data then you can choose data in below ways:

```
//Populate all main categories
public List<Category>  MainCategories { get; set; }

//Populate all sub and sub categories
public List<Category> SubCategories { get; set; }
```

At the event `rptrMainCategories_ItemDataBound` write below code and bind to repeater:

```
List<Category> subCategory = SubCategories.Where(c => c.SubCategoryId = yourSubCategoryID);
rptrSubCategories.DataSource = subCategory ;
rptrSubCategories.DataBind();
```

At the event `rptrSubCategories_ItemDataBound` write below code and bind to repeater:

```
List<Category> subSubCategory = SubCategories.Where(c => c.SubSubCategoryId = yourSubSubCategoryID);
rptrSubSubCategory.DataSource = subSubCategory ;
rptrSubSubCategory.DataBind();
```

Comment: Hello @user560498, I've changed and updated my answer, please have a look now, thanks for your time.

Comment: thanks, how do I get dataTableMainCategories in rptrMainCategories_ItemDataBound ? I want to get it only once ?

Comment: You'll need two DataTable (dataTableMainCategories and dataTableCategories; ) as descried above, where dataTableMainCategories holds main category and dataTableCategories contains sub and sub sub category, if you need to show on page load then just populated these data table in you `Page_Load` event, `dataTableCategories` will be available both in `rptrMainCategories_ItemDataBound` and `rptrSubCategories_ItemDataBound` event. Please let me know the update, thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi, I have List<List<T>>, I am using 3 level repeater, on the event "OnItemDataBound" of 1st repeater how do i get the list of data that was bound